# element-wise maximum of multidimensional arrays

Tags: matlab, max

Given two arrays, say:

```
A = [1 2  4 5; 
     6 11 3 54];

B = [2 2  6  3; 
     5 12 60 54];
```

I would like to generate the array:

```
C = [2 2  6  5; 
     6 12 60 54];
```

Using built-in MATLAB functions , i.e. in a single line, not in loops. notice that with real data, I'm talking about very large multidimensional arrays.

Comment: As per [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302152/if-another-question-is-the-answer-is-it-a-duplicate): Possible duplicate of [How to find the maximum of multiple arrays in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247714/how-to-find-the-maximum-of-multiple-arrays-in-matlab). The answer is found in the body of the linked question.

Comment: @Dev-iL I don't think the question linked counts as a duplicate. Yes, it does have `max(x,y)` in the question body but it is in a completely different context. That question states that this command will return the array containing the maximum value (which is actually incorrect) whereas this question is about finding the element-wise maxima. Someone reading this question and not knowing the answer already, may very well not realise that that one line in the question of the duplicate is infact the answer as there is nothing there to contextualize it.

Comment: @Dan would [`min` instead of `max`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504954/octave-matlab-min-of-two-vectors) be an acceptable dupe? We're still talking about an rtfm-able question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak that is very close. The only difference being that it takes in vectors instead of matrices. Personally I wouldn't mind either way with that question. Agreed regarding RTFM on this one. If there weren't already over-complicated answers here, I would probably have just replied with that as a comment instead of answering to be honest. But the answers provided made me think maybe people don't know about that particular usage of `max`.

Comment: Another similar question is this one: [Find the max between two arrays and then concatenate the cells of the max array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20138331/3372061).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is exactly what the `max` function does by default:

```
C = max(A,B)
```